# py.test with xdist is not executing tests parametrized with random values

Tags: python, pytest, xdist

Does anybody noticed the following strange behaviour for pytest and xdist.

When trying to run the test that is parametrized with some randomly selected values the test are not actualy run. 
The same test is executed without any problems if xdist is not used.

Following code can be used to reproduce this.

```
import pytest
import random

PARAMS_NUMBER = 3
PARAMS = []

for i in range(PARAMS_NUMBER):
    PARAMS.append(random.randrange(0, 1000))

@pytest.mark.parametrize('rand_par', PARAMS)
def test_random_param(rand_par):

    assert 500 > rand_par
```

Without xdists it works fine.

With xdist no test is executed at all with the following output

```
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 2.7.3 -- py-1.4.24 -- pytest-2.6.2
plugins: xdist
gw0 [3] / gw1 [3] / gw2 [3] / gw3 [3]
scheduling tests via LoadScheduling

==============================  in 1.93 seconds ===============================
```

Versions I'm using:

- python 2.7.3
- pytest 2.6.2
- pytest-xdist 1.11

Additional note:

With some older versions (xdist 1.8 and pytest 2.4.X or 2.5.X do not remember exactly) the xdist was stopping on assertion in dsession.py

```
assert collection == col
```

Thanks in advance for any help how to solve it or at least workaround it :)

Comment: Maybe some code is loading your .py file more than once, and then it's not finding the test parameters from the first load (because they are randomly different)?

Comment: @ArminRigo from what I investigated it seems that each subprocess is collecting the tests and then xdist is checking if every subprocess gathered the same set of tests (in case of random parameters we get different set of params for each subprocess)

Answer (score 2):

So here is the code after Armins hint :)

```
import pytest
import random

PARAMS_NUMBER = 3
PARAMS = []

for i in range(PARAMS_NUMBER):
    PARAMS.append(1000)

@pytest.mark.parametrize('rand_par', PARAMS)
def test_random_param(rand_par):

    par_val = random.randrange(0, rand_par)
    assert 500 > par_val
```

And it runs test 3 times with randomly selected value.

**Update:**
I have created an issue for xdist project and it is resolved in the meaning of returning reasonable info for user.

More info can be found here [py.test with xdist is not executing tests parametrized with random values](https://bitbucket.org/hpk42/pytest/issue/594/pytest-with-xdist-is-not-executing-tests)

Answer (score 1):

A workaround would be to parametrize with reproducible (but meaningless) values, like all numbers between 0 and `PARAMS_NUMBER-1`.  Then each test can individually pick a random value when it runs.  In order to know which random value it picked (to reproduce in case of crash), each test should print it first.  At least that's what I do with some non-xdist tests; I hope it works too with xdist, i.e. the prints are correctly propagated to the parent process and only shown if the individual test fails (or py.test is run with -s).

Comment: Hey thanks for the hint. I've made a workaround for given example. It might be a little dirty (e.g. it seems that all tests were collected with the same set of parameters :( and inside the test the real parameter values are randomly selected).