# py.test with xdist skipping all the tests with -n > 1

Tags: python, parallel-processing, pytest, xdist

My tests take 2 minutes to run:

```
$ py.test
================================================= test session starts =================================================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.8 -- py-1.4.24 -- pytest-2.5.2
plugins: cov, xdist
collected 2249 items 

«lots of file names»
====================================== 2242 passed, 7 skipped in 120.01 seconds =======================================
```

…so I thought I'll try the `xdist` plugin to run them in parallel. So, I did:

```
$ pip install pytest-xdist
$ py.test -n 2
================================================= test session starts =================================================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.8 -- py-1.4.24 -- pytest-2.5.2
plugins: cov, xdist
gw0 [2249] / gw1 [2249]
scheduling tests via LoadScheduling

==================================================  in 2.65 seconds ===================================================
```

2 seconds would be a marvelous speedup… though I kind of think no tests are run—some dots would show up, wouldn't they? However, if I do "parallel" run with just a single process…

```
$ py.test -n 1
================================================= test session starts =================================================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.8 -- py-1.4.24 -- pytest-2.5.2
plugins: cov, xdist
gw0 [2249]
scheduling tests via LoadScheduling
....«lots and lots of dots»........
====================================== 2242 passed, 7 skipped in 122.27 seconds =======================================
```

…then the time's back to normal.

How can I make `xdist` plugin actually run the tests?

UPDATE:

An answer to Bruno Oliveira question:

```
$ py.test -n 4 -vv
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.8 -- py-1.4.24 -- pytest-2.5.2 -- /home/liori/proj/.ve/bin/python2
plugins: cov, xdist
[gw0] linux2 Python 2.7.8 cwd: /home/liori/proj/src
[gw1] linux2 Python 2.7.8 cwd: /home/liori/proj/src
[gw2] linux2 Python 2.7.8 cwd: /home/liori/proj/src
[gw3] linux2 Python 2.7.8 cwd: /home/liori/proj/src
[gw0] Python 2.7.8 (default, Aug 23 2014, 21:00:50)  -- [GCC 4.9.1]
[gw1] Python 2.7.8 (default, Aug 23 2014, 21:00:50)  -- [GCC 4.9.1]
[gw2] Python 2.7.8 (default, Aug 23 2014, 21:00:50)  -- [GCC 4.9.1]
[gw3] Python 2.7.8 (default, Aug 23 2014, 21:00:50)  -- [GCC 4.9.1]
gw0 [2254] / gw1 [2254] / gw2 [2254] / gw3 [2254]
scheduling tests via LoadScheduling

===============================  in 4.63 seconds ===============================
```

Comment: Running `py.test -n4 -vv` produces anything useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used randomized values for parametrizing my tests, as suggested by Marek. However, his suggestion pushed me towards checking another hypothesis, which seems to be true: `xdist` requires that parametrizations for the tests are generated always in the same order.

In my specific case, I generated by parametrizations by iterating over a `set` of strings. However, this iteration depends on the specific values the strings hash to, and these values might be different for every process. Therefore, whereas I was always generating exactly the same parametrizations, they were in different order.

A simple test case that shows the problem:

```
import pytest

my_names = {'john', 'kate', 'alfred', 'paul', 'mary'}

@pytest.mark.parametrize('name', list(my_names), ids=list(my_names))
def test_is_name_short(name):
    assert len(name) < 7
```

Run with `PYTHONHASHSEED=random py.test -n 4` to make sure you trigger randomized hashing for strings.

A simple workaround is to enforce a specific ordering on the tests, e.g. by sorting them by some parameter:

```
my_names = sorted(my_names)
```

I have submitted to py.test's bugtracker a suggestion to [make `xdist` sort parametrizations](https://bitbucket.org/hpk42/pytest/issue/596/xdist-is-not-executing-tests-if-their) for comparison to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 1):

For me looks like similar issue I've noticed :)

Are Your tests somehow randomly parametrized?
If yes please take a look at [py.test with xdist is not executing tests parametrized with random values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25958659/py-test-with-xdist-is-not-executing-tests-parametrized-with-random-values)

Both in Your and my case it is actually not skipping (if it is really skipped then You would have X skipped in the summary)

Comment: Well, I haven't explicitly used random in my tests, but the culprit seems to be a non-deterministic *order* of tests during collection phase… thanks for hint.